# Incorrect type. Expected "string". in package.json

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, package.json

I insert the following command into my package.json in `dependencies` but there's an error saying, *Incorrect type. Expected "string".* I have no idea why this is happening. I tried removing the doublequotes of the *nohoist* and I got an error that *doublequotes* must be place between it and when I put it back I got the error as in the title. What can I do here ?

```
"workspaces": {
        "nohoist": [
          "@tailwindcss/forms",
          "@tailwindcss/forms/**"
        ]
    }
```

into this :

```
{
  "name": "mymbsa",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "license": "MIT",
  "dependencies": {
    "@redux-saga/core": "^1.1.3",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.11.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.1.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.1.10",
    "@types/jest": "^26.0.15",
    "@types/node": "^12.0.0",
    "@types/react": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^17.0.0",
    "@types/react-icons": "^3.0.0",
    "@types/react-redux": "^7.1.20",
    "@types/react-router-dom": "^5.3.2",
    "@types/react-table": "^7.7.9",
    "@types/redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.2",
    "@types/redux-logger": "^3.0.9",
    "@types/redux-saga": "^0.10.5",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.3",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "axios-logger": "^2.6.2",
    "date-fns": "^2.29.1",
    "dotenv": "^14.2.0",
    "downloadjs": "^1.4.7",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "framer-motion": "^4.1.17",
    "html-entities": "^2.3.2",
    "html-react-parser": "^3.0.8",
    "leaflet": "^1.8.0",
    "lodash.throttle": "^4.1.1",
    "md5": "^2.3.0",
    "moment": "^2.29.1",
    "moment-timezone": "^0.5.34",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.17.1",
    "pin-input-react": "^1.0.5",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-big-calendar": "^1.5.0",
    "react-circle": "^1.1.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^4.8.0",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-icons": "^4.3.1",
    "react-intl": "^5.23.0",
    "react-js-pagination": "^3.0.3",
    "react-leaflet": "^4.0.1",
    "react-markdown": "^7.1.1",
    "react-moment": "^1.1.1",
    "react-multi-carousel": "^2.6.5",
    "react-password-checklist": "^1.3.3",
    "react-perfect-scrollbar": "^1.5.8",
    "react-pin-field": "^2.0.0-beta.2",
    "react-pin-input": "^1.0.1",
    "react-redux": "^7.2.6",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.1.1",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-select": "^5.2.1",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "react-tooltip": "^4.2.21",
    "redux": "^4.1.2",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.9",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0",
    "redux-saga": "^1.1.3",
    "sweetalert2": "^11.1.10",
    "sweetalert2-react-content": "^4.2.0",
    "tailwind-merge": "^1.8.0",
    "tw-elements": "^1.0.0-alpha12",
    "typescript": "^4.1.2",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "web-vitals": "^1.0.1",
    "yup": "^0.32.11",
    "workspaces": {
        "nohoist": [
          "@tailwindcss/forms",
          "@tailwindcss/forms/**"
        ]
    }
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "node generate-version.js && craco build",
    "test": "craco test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject",
    "deploy": "sh deploy.sh"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": [
    ">0.2%",
    "not dead",
    "not op_mini all"
  ],
  "devDependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.1.0",
    "@types/leaflet": "^1.7.11",
    "@types/react-big-calendar": "^0.38.1",
    "autoprefixer": "^9",
    "postcss": "^7",
    "tailwind-scroll-behavior": "^1.0.0",
    "tailwindcss": "npm:@tailwindcss/postcss7-compat"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "16.9.53",
    "@types/react-dom": "16.9.8"
  }
}
```

Here are the full error when i ran `yarn start` :

```
$ yarn start
yarn run v1.22.19
$ craco start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933
  const err = new Error(message);
              ^

Error: Cannot find module 'tailwindcss'
Require stack:
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/craco.config.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerBase.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/Explorer.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/config.js
- /home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/scripts/start.js
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:102:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/craco.config.js:4:19)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1105:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1159:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:981:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:822:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1005:19) {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: [
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/craco.config.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/loaders.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/ExplorerBase.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/Explorer.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/cosmiconfig/dist/index.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/lib/config.js',
    '/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/node_modules/@craco/craco/dist/scripts/start.js'
  ]
}
```

Comment: You need to share the full error (stack trace) as the json is valid

Comment: @matiaslauriti I've updated the full error (stack trace) in my post

Comment: Why do you have `devDependencies`? Move all `devDependencies` to `dependencies` and try again

Comment: i just moved all `devDependencies` to `dependencies`, now i got this error when i ran `yarn start`, `error An unexpected error occurred: "The \"path\" argument must be of type string. Received [Object: null prototype]".
info If you think this is a bug, please open a bug report with the information provided in "/home/jabrij93/mymbsa/yarn-error.log".`

Comment: After moving, did you run `yarn install`? You need to trigger everything again, with the updated `package.json`, then you can run `yarn start`

Comment: @matiaslauriti I start again and re-run everything, when i ran yarn start, i got an error  `throw new Error("Your current version of react-scripts(".concat(version, ") is not supported by this version of CRACO. Please try updating react-scripts to the latest version:\n\n") +
              ^

Error: Your current version of react-scripts(4.0.3) is not supported by this version of CRACO. Please try updating react-scripts to the latest version: ...` .. i tried upgrading it by using the command, `yarn upgrade react-scripts`  but the same error still remains

Comment: updated : i upgraded the react-scripts version to 5.0.1 and a new error come out, Cannot find module 'tailwindcss' ..so I ran a command, npm install tailwindcss, this error occur, `npm WARN deprecated @types/redux-saga@0.10.5: This is a stub types definition for redux-saga (https://github.com/redux-saga/redux-saga). redux-saga provides its own type definitions, so you don't need @types/redux-saga installed!
npm ERR! Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'match')`

Comment: I have no idea about the latest error, I would say remove it, as the error says. `npm remove @types/redux-saga`